# .net Printing with staple

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument

In my project i have to print a liste of images files (.png) with differents settings, and i ca do it without problem using the native .Net System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument classe :

- PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.**Landscape** allow me to change the orientation
- PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.**PaperSize** allow me to change the papersize to use
- PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.**Duplex** allow me to change the duplexing mode

The only thing i am not able to do is to define the Stapling property ??
After spending a lot of time of searching, i am very dissapointed on how to do this :

- Is it possible to do it using the PrintDocument classe and its sub-classes ??
- Do i have to use a PrintTicket as described in  [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket.stapling(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

But if the solution is to use the print ticket class, i 've two others questions :

1. How do i attach the printing of an existing image file (using a printjob, a PrintDocument ???)
2. Are thoses classes only available for using XPS document ?

Important constraint : there is no GUI (because the program prints a lot of files in batch mode), so the user cannot change interactivly the staple option.

Comment: A stapling option is a custom printer device driver option that is not wrapped by Windows.  The user would normally use Control Panel > Devices and Printers > right-click the printer > Printing preferences.  If this needs to be configurable for each printing job then you can use the PrintDialog class, its Preferences button exposes the same property sheets.

Comment: @HansPassant : sorry bu i didn't mention the is no gui to allow the user to change settings, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after spending few more hours of search, i've found the right answer to get and set specific printer settings.

Thanks to this [Good Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488737/Storing-and-recalling-printer-settings-in-Csharp-n), i did understand that in order to get/set all the settings of a printer, i have to deal with the DevMode structure of the printer.

Drawbacks :

- the DevMode structure is specific to a driver, and also to an operating system
- you have to maintain a list of DevMode address for each parameters you want to change

Benefits :

- you can access all the functions offered by a printer (even printing on tee-shirt, or saving mode....)
- the project in the link show a small interface to get/set/examine what parameter have been changed using the Pinter Dialog Settings window. So you yan easily by code change on the fly